# Do I have to run clearInterval if I implemented setInterval like this

Tags: javascript

```
function start() {
    // code goes here
    setInterval(start, 1800000);
}

start();
```

as opposed to:

```
setInterval(start, 1800000);
```

I want to run start() immediately after I start my node.js server rather than wait 1800000 milliseconds.

Since I am repeatedly calling the setInterval function, do I have to clear it with clearInterval? How would I do so if that were the case?

Comment: You can just do `start(); setInterval(start, 1800000);`.

Comment: _"How would I do so if that were the case?"_ - Just check the documentation including the examples -> [MDN: `setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Comment: note: if you put `setInterval(start, 1800000);` inside of `start`, every 30 minutes  you'll duplicate the times that `start` is called. So after 2 hours, `start` will be called 8 times at once

Answer (score 1):

> Since I am repeatedly calling the setInterval function, do I have to
>   clear it with clearInterval?

You are basically creating a new *timer* every time `start` method is invoked, just replace `setInterval` with `setTimeout` since you are invoking `start` method again anyways which will create a new *timer* on every invocation.

```
function start() {
    // code goes here
    setTimeout(start, 1800000);
}

start();
```